# How to go to git message commit command line prompt?

Tags: git

I want to go to the git commit command prompt to add a multi-line message command line in windows. I am able to add commit in a single line using command but I want to add multiple lines of message.

Comment: What have you set as your git editor?

Comment: I havent set it to anything. I want to add commit message to individual files

Comment: So you'd like to use `git commit -m <msg>` where `msg` spans multiple lines?

Comment: @matt it seems like the question revolves around git not kicking off to an editor, but rather passing multi-line `-m` value on the command line.

Comment: But if the editor is vim you're still on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a multiline message using `-m`, just pass in a multiline message as the value of that option.  E.g., I can write (assuming a `bash` shell):

```
$ git commit -m $'This is\n\nThis is only a test'
```

And I get:

```
commit 676ffa32c7adf88e4abafdacf9ba55f9526cd454 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@oddbit.com>
Date:   Mon Aug 9 10:52:49 2021 -0400

    This is a test

    This is only a test
```

I could also write instead (assuming any posix-y shell):

```
$ git commit -m 'This is a test

This is only a test'
```

That results in the same thing.

If you're working with Powershell instead, you can probably do something similar.